# Security issues using URL parameters

Tags: security

I'm writing a custom router for Magento. Here's a code snippet of what I'm doing in the match() method:

```
$pathInfo = $request->getPathInfo();
$splitPath = explode('/', $pathInfo);
$category = $splitPath[1];
....
$categoriesCollection->addAttributeToFilter('url_key', array('eq' => $category));
```

My question is this: is it safe to assume that the underlying models will take care of any SQL injection attacks etc, or should I be worrying about preventing these problems?

Many thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's pretty safe to assume the values will be escaped properly to prevent SQL injection.
All parameters pass through the `Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract::quoteInto()` method that should make it safe.
Is somehow you find a vulnerability in this, then the issue is with Zend Framework, not Magento itself.